# How to make an access query criteria OR statement active only when a parameter has certain values?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, criteria

I have this query:

```
SELECT t_Data.ID, t_Data.Location, t_Data.[VG's], t_Data.BinSize, t_Data.Date, t_Data.Time, t_Data.RPM001, t_Data.POW001, t_Data.WSP001, t_Data.YAW001, t_Data.RPM002, t_Data.POW002, t_Data.WSP002, t_Data.YAW002
FROM t_Data
WHERE (((t_Data.Location)=[Forms]![f_Main]![LocationCombo]) AND ((t_Data.BinSize)=[Forms]![f_Main]![BinSizeCombo]) AND ((t_Data.POW001)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimit] And (t_Data.POW001)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimit]) AND ((t_Data.WSP001)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP001)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP001)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP001)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text]) AND ((t_Data.YAW001)>=Sector1_dsp() And (t_Data.YAW001)<=Sector2_dsp()) AND ((t_Data.POW002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimit_Text] And (t_Data.POW002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimit_Text] And (t_Data.POW002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimit_Text] And (t_Data.POW002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimit_Text]) AND ((t_Data.WSP002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text]) AND ((t_Data.YAW002)>=Sector1_dsp() And (t_Data.YAW002)<=Sector2_dsp())) OR (((t_Data.Location)=[Forms]![f_Main]![LocationCombo]) AND ((t_Data.BinSize)=[Forms]![f_Main]![BinSizeCombo]) AND ((t_Data.POW001)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimit] And (t_Data.POW001)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimit]) AND ((t_Data.WSP001)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP001)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP001)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP001)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text]) AND ((t_Data.YAW001)>=Sector3_dsp() And (t_Data.YAW001)<=Sector4_dsp()) AND ((t_Data.POW002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimit_Text] And (t_Data.POW002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimit_Text] And (t_Data.POW002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimit_Text] And (t_Data.POW002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimit_Text]) AND ((t_Data.WSP002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP002)>[Forms]![f_Main]![LowerLimitMs_Text] And (t_Data.WSP002)<[Forms]![f_Main]![UpperLimitMs_Text]) AND ((t_Data.YAW002)>=Sector3_dsp() And (t_Data.YAW002)<=Sector4_dsp()));
```

The fields called `YAW001` and `YAW002` are the direction of a wind turbine.

I have a form with a function where it is possible to choose only wind from north, north is 0 degrees. East is 90 degrees.

The problem is that I have the limits working just fine as long as the angle is 0->360 degrees. When i choose to see fx a 90 degree windows from north, i need values that are between 360-90/2 and 360+90/2. I then get a criteria as:

```
Yaw001 > 315 AND Yaw001 < 405
```

But since the values needed are from 315 to 45 degrees, i have a problem.
I need it to see that if the limit is above 360, the criteria should then be

```
Yaw001 > 315 OR Yaw001 < 45
```

How do i crack this one?

The same applies for `Yaw002`.

The system may also be rotated counter clockwise so that the desired values are

```
Yaw001 < -45 AND Yaw001 < 45
```

And again the lowest value is 0, so it would need to be

```
Yaw001 > 315 OR Yaw001 < 45
```

I have tried using this statement in OR:

```
IIf(Sector4_dsp()>360;<=Sector4_dsp()-360;<0)
```

But even if it is true, it does not return the criteria `<=Sector4_dsp()-360`.

I hope you follow me here.

Best regards, Emil.

Comment: Use three criterias - (angle between someting) OR (angle - 360 between someting) OR (angle + 360 between something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have MSAccess to hand but surely the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation would give you what you need? In your SQL query use (angle MOD 360). For example, (-45 MOD 360) = 315, (405 MOD 360) = 45.

**Edit, adding sample condition expressions**

Assuming an arc of 90 degrees either side of North;

```
direction = 0
min = (direction - 90/2 mod 360)
max = (direction + 90/2 mod 360)
Yaw001 = Yaw001 mod 360
```

then

```
(min <= max and Yaw001 >= min and Yaw001 =< max) or (min > max and (Yaw001 > min or Yaw001 < max)
```

Comment: I am not familia with x MOD 360 - Can you give me a brief description?

Comment: I see your point, but i still need the criteria to change. The problem is not to subtract 360 or add 360. It is to tell the query that now it is just "Above 290 OR Below 40". Usually, it is in between two values (Above 10 AND Below 50"). But when it passes 0 or 360, it changes from AND to OR... I cant get that to work...

Comment: Please see what i have added in the buttom of the original question, the IIF statement.

Comment: Ah, i see the point. I guess that will also work. Actually, i got it to work just before. The solution i used was to just add an OR criteria of >Yaw001-360. Its requires 4 lines alone which creates quite a large SQL code. But it will do. I will look into yours if i hit more walls. Thank you for your time.